# PHP Notice: Only variables should be assigned by reference

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, httpd.conf, php-7.2

I am getting the following error.

> PHP Notice:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in
> /var/www/html/plugins/system/jxtcadminlock/jxtcadminlock.php

I am usig PHP 7.2

And the 39th line of the file(/var/www/html/plugins/system/jxtcadminlock/jxtcadminlock.php) is as below.

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('admin');
```

I need to fix this without upgrading joomla.

Comment: 1. You should not be using J2.5 anymore.  2. You should post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  I would request the migration of this page to Joomla, but this question is very incomplete and the users there would only tell you to upgrade your Joomla version.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is just a notice. If you aren't going to fix your codebase manually to make it PHP/7 compliant you can just ignore it.

If I'm not wrong that's the old PHP/4 syntax, obsoleted in 2004, to deal with the fact that objects used to be passed by value rather than reference. It's quickly mentioned in the [Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php) guide.

Since PHP/5 you can drop the `&` sign altogether. However, it's very likely that this isn't the only compatibility issue.